# Android game board with irregular board spaces

Tags: android

I'm creating an Android board game with several differently shaped board spaces (like Risk).

I want to be sure that my board appears correct and that OnTouchListeners stay in place on the GUI regardless of screen size/resolution.

Possible solutions I have thought of and their problems:

1. Create a single image for the board and assign OnTouchListeners based upon pixel geometry. Problem: If the user's display is a different resolution, my Listener might not be under the same pixels as my image (right?)
2. Create several ImageButtons and arrange them together. Problem: the ImageButtons might get rearranged based upon the display and I would end up with overlapping spaces or gaps.
3. Use Android custom drawing. If I do this, how would I link my Listeners to my Canvas and be sure that they are synced?

Basic question:
How to be sure that listeners sync with graphics in a GUI that uses irregular geometry?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on an app with irregular touch areas so I can give you guidance on one way to achieve this.

Start with a single image for your entire board.  This image is going to have a certain ("intrinsic") width and height regardless of any device resolutions.

Now here comes the tedious part.  You (or maybe your graphic designer) will need to plot out coordinates of an irregular polygon for each touch area.   These will be constants to your application.

When you are displaying your board, if you are zooming and panning on the image, you want to keep track of the transform matrix for the display.  When the user touches the screen, you will get x,y coordinates from `OnTouchListener` and for those to be useful, you will have to "de-transform" the x,y to normalize it against the intrinsic dimensions of the board and your polygons.

We rolled our own hit-testing logic using an algorithm from http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/, but you can also try this: Create a `Path` out of your polygon coordinates (using `moveTo()`, `lineTo()`, and `close()`), then assign the `Path` to a `Region` using `Region.setPath()`.  Once you have that, supposedly you should be able to hit-test using `Region.contains(x,y)`, but I've never tried it so I can't guarantee that's going to work.